# Using Basic Authentication with Web Browser Control for WP8

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am trying add in support for basic auth using a WebBrowser control by doing this:

```
string hdr = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{username}" + ":" + "{password}")) + System.Environment.NewLine;

webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://MyTestWebsite.com/"), null, hdr);
```

However, when Navigate is called, the WebBrowser will not load the page. And LoadCompleted/Navigated was never called. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UriBuilder uriSite = new UriBuilder("http://MyTestWebsite.com/");
uriSite.UserName = UserNameAuth;
uriSite.Password = PasswordAuth;
WebBrowser.Navigate(uriSite.Uri);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the WebBrowser does not load the page using the method above. However I can see in fiddler that there is a success response coming back, but the WebBrowser is not loading the page. Do you know why this could be happening?